# Как удалить элемент массива с определенным значением?

Tags: javascript, массивы

Есть массив объектов.

```
 var massiv =[{name:'Black', value :'a'},
    {name:'Blue',value :'a'},
    {name:'Blonde',value :'b' },
    {name:'Alabaster', value :'b'},
    {name:'Red', value :'a'}];
```

Есть переменная `edinica = 1`.

Как удалить элементы массива со значением `value :'b'`при условии, что переменная `edinica = 1`?

Comment: Посмотрите на метод filter у Array. Вот пример использования https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: Поправил свой ответ, теперь там всё нормально

Answer (score 2):

Можно написать всё самому, вручную

```js
const arr = [
    {name:'Black', value :'a'},
    {name:'Blue',value :'a'},
    {name:'Blonde',value :'b'},
    {name:'Alabaster', value :'b'},
    {name:'Red', value :'a'}
];

function cycle(arr) {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) { // пройтись по все элементам массива
    if (typeof(arr[i]) === 'object' && arr[i].value === 'b') { // если элемент массива является объектом, и у этого объекта поле value равняется 'b' и является строкой
      arr.splice(i, 1); // удалить элемент из массива
      i--; // уменьшить итератор на единицу
    }
  }
  return arr; // вернуть массив как результат выполнения функции
}

let number = 1;
let newArr;

if (number === 1) { // если переменная number равняется 1 и является числом, то выполнять код
  newArr = cycle(arr); // newArr равняется результату выполнения функции cycle
  console.log(newArr);
}
```

Или можно использовать функцию `filer`, которая встроена в массивы JavaScript:

```js
const arr = [
    {name:'Black', value :'a'},
    {name:'Blue',value :'a'},
    {name:'Blonde',value :'b'},
    {name:'Alabaster', value :'b'},
    {name:'Red', value :'a'}
];


let number = 1;
let newArr;

if (number === 1) { // если переменная number равняется 1 и является числом, то выполнять код
  newArr = arr.filter((item) => typeof(item) === 'object' && item.value !== 'b'); // отфильтровать массив, в котором подходить под условие будут только те объекты у которых поле value не равняется 'b' и не является строкой
   console.log(newArr);
}
```